# The most perplexing jquery issue i've ever run into

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This very simple function to calculate the scroll of the page works just fine on jsfiddle, but I can't get it working on my page.

http://jsfiddle.net/SnJXQ/2/

The function is thus:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {


        var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());

        $('.bar-long').css('width', scrollPercent +"%"  );

    });
 });
```

Simple, right? Thing is, it never applies the css to the bar-long class div on my local environment, just strange.

So I thought it might be an issue with window scroll function, so I done this:-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut


    $(window).scroll(function() {


        var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());

        $('.bar-long').css('width', scrollPercent +"%"  );

    });




        $(window).scroll(function() {    
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 100) {
                $("body").addClass("scrolled");
            } else {
                $("body").removeClass("scrolled");
            }
        });



});
```

Second function to test that I wasn't making an utterly stupid mistake, I wasn't, second function works just fine.

I'm running WordPress with their bundled version of jQuery1.11.1, hence the noconflict jQuery qualifier.

I even went as far as to paste in my entire css to jsfiddle along with a copy/pasta of my sites html, worked just fine.

I've disabled other scripts on the site, no conflict with those, no errors in console.

Just confused, really confused.

EDIT:- After some console logging;

```
        console.log($(window).height());

        console.log($(document).height());

        console.log ($(document).height() - $(window).height());

=

5541 
5541 
0
```

So it thinks the window height and the document height are the same, which they are not. Hrmm.

Comment: Have you tried this to make sure you don't have some other css overriding?  Change $('.bar-long').css('width', scrollPercent +"%"  ); to $('.bar-long').css('width', scrollPercent +"% !important"  );

Comment: What do you see when you log things to the console? e.g. put `console.log($('.bar-long').length); // how many .bar-long elements are there?` and `console.log(scrollPercent); // What is scrollPercent coming out as?` after the `var scrollPercent =...` line?

Comment: scrollPercent is coming out as 'infinity' in the console, I'm super confused.

Comment: A long shot, but do you have a public URL we can see where you have the problem?

Comment: Console.log everything and see where your math is going wrong.

Comment: +1 to Archer just for having the name of my favorite show!!

Comment: I'd say the math isn't going wrong - something else is interfering.  The fiddle example works fine.

Comment: @Archer I'm afraid not just now, if there's no solution I'll throw it up, but that's 20 minutes of faffing around for a WP theme.

Comment: In that case, scroll down the page so you know there *should* be some effect, and then start inspecting elements and checking the CSS.  Something is obviously different between your site and the fiddle example.

Comment: Really weird indeed. I put everything in a local file on my machine and it works perfectly. The only explanation would be what @Scottie said.

Comment: The most dramatic title on SO I've ever run in into!

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester it really should be changed to something more descriptive of the problem.

Comment: agreed, this sounds like a buzzfeed headline, perhaps change it to something with actual context.

Comment: I try my best, @MDeSchaepmeester, perhaps I should start writing clickbair articles for buzzfeed...

Comment: well @turbo2oh, snap...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

Holy Christ almighty, it was because chrome gets confused with doctypes and thinks window/document height are the same if you mess that up, I was using this: 
`<!DOCTYPE html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>`, I removed the php from it and now it works just fine.

Thanks to everyone that helped anyway. A good FYI, doctypes are important.

Comment: It isn't just Chrome that gets confused with DOCTYPES; it is important to all browsers, but some react differently than others to malformed code. Declare your language attributes in the <html> tag: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-root-element

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, it sounds like your code is trying to divide by zero.

If `$(document).height() - $(window).height()` is `0`, you're doing `100 * $(window).scrollTop() / 0`, which according to my firefox console comes out as `Infinity`.

You can't really set `width: Infinity%;` on an element, so check first! Something like this:

```
// Avoid a divide by zero error
var docHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
if (docHeight < 1) {
    docHeight = $(document).height();
}
var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / docHeight);
```

Answer (score -1):

## It's likely an overriding style

Try changing the class or enhancing the specificity of your selector `$('.parent-div .bar-long')`, etc.

Also, inspect the computed styles in your dev tools (Chrome inspector, Firebug, etc.) to see what styles in the cascade are being applied or overridden.

Comment: No styles are being applied, I don't think it's a css problem as inline styles would overwrite any that were messing with it anyway.

I scroll - zero css applied to the div.

Comment: @andy This was a legitimate answer (even if not correct), so I'm surprised by the down vote. You don't have to have styles applied directly to .bar-long for the cascade to affect the element. Somewhere in the styles there could be something like `div { width: 0 }` which would apply. And any style that has `!important` applied would override inline styles. So, it was a worthwhile effort for me to suggest this answer. Especially given the fact that you didn't provide a link to the real source and you hadn't yet posted the update with the console.log info about window vs document heights.

Comment: @andy "voting down a post signals ... that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information." http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote What do you think about changing that vote?

Comment: My apologies. I'm afraid it won't let me change it though since it's been more than 6 hours. Sincerely sorry!